# printf only printing while passing the last index value of an array of class object

Tags: java, system.out

I created a class object array and but now when I try to print it using printf method then it doesn't print those values, I tried checking if the values are correct using println and it works fine with it. One more thing which was weird is that when I pass the end index of the array then it prints them. for example class object array is of size 20 (0-19), when I pass 19th index to the method which prints it then it is working but for 0-18 it is not working.

```
package com.insurance.company;

import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Lenovo
 */
public class InsuranceCompany {
    private String companyName;
    private String telephone;
    private String webAddress;
    private double brokerPercentage;
    private String description;
    private List<String> insuranceTypes;

    public InsuranceCompany(){}
    public InsuranceCompany(String companyName, String telephone, String webAddress, double brokerPercentage, String description, List<String> insuranceTypes) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.telephone = telephone;
        this.webAddress = webAddress;
        this.brokerPercentage = brokerPercentage;
        this.description = description;
        this.insuranceTypes = insuranceTypes;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(companyName);
        sb.append(" " + telephone);
        sb.append(" " + webAddress);
        for(int i = 0; i < insuranceTypes.size(); i++){
            sb.append(" " + insuranceTypes.get(i));
        }
        sb.append(" " + brokerPercentage);
        sb.append(" " + description);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public String getWebAddress() {
        return webAddress;
    }

    public double getBrokerPercentage() {
        return brokerPercentage;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public List<String> getInsuranceTypes() {
        return insuranceTypes;
    }
    
}
```

```
package com.insurance.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class InsurancePortal {
    //function to load data from file
    private static String loadDataFromFile(String path)throws Exception{
        String data;
        data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));
        return data;
    }
    //function to list all insurance companies
    private static void listInuranceCompanies(InsuranceCompany[] company){
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.printf("| %3s | %-20s | %-111s |%n", "ID", "Company Name", "Cover Types");
        //System.out.flush();
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        for(int j = 0; j < company.length; j++){
            System.out.printf("| %3d | %-20s |", j+1, company[j].getCompanyName());
        for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
            if(i < company[j].getInsuranceTypes().size()){
                System.out.printf(" %15S", company[j].getInsuranceTypes().get(i));
            }else{
                System.out.printf(" %15s", " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print(" |\n");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
    }
    //function to search cover
    public static void listSingleCompanyDetails(InsuranceCompany selectedCompany){
        System.out.println(selectedCompany.getCompanyName()+"\n--------------------------------------------------");
        //System.out.flush();
        System.out.printf("| %-18S | %-28S |%n", selectedCompany.getCompanyName(), selectedCompany.getDescription());
        //System.out.flush();
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------");
    }
    
    public static void main(String arge[]) throws Exception{
        String dataFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "insurance-data.txt";
        String[] data = loadDataFromFile(dataFile).split("\n");
        /*for(String str: data){
            System.out.println(str);
        }*/
        int rows = data.length;
        InsuranceCompany[] company = new InsuranceCompany[rows];
        //Initialising objects for every row of data in the file
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
            String row = data[j];
            //System.out.println(row);
            String companyName, telephone, webAddress, description;
            double brokerPercentage;
            List<String> insuranceTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        
            //Splitting for Company Name
            String[] splittedArray = row.split(":", 2);
            companyName = splittedArray[0];
            row = splittedArray[1];
        
            //Splitting for telephone
            splittedArray = row.split(":", 2);
            telephone = splittedArray[0];
            row = splittedArray[1];
            
            //splitting for web address
            splittedArray = row.split(":", 2);
            webAddress = splittedArray[0];
            row = splittedArray[1];
        
            //splitiing for insurance types
            splittedArray = row.split(":", 2);
            String[] insuranceTypeList = splittedArray[0].split(",");
            for(String str : insuranceTypeList){
                insuranceTypes.add(str);
            }
            row = splittedArray[1];
        
            //splitting for broker percentage
            splittedArray = row.split(":", 2);
            brokerPercentage = Double.parseDouble(splittedArray[0]);
            row = splittedArray[1];
        
            //splitting for description
            splittedArray = row.split(":", 2);
            description = splittedArray[0];
            //System.out.println(companyName+ " " + telephone + " " +webAddress + " " + brokerPercentage + " " + description);
            /*for(int i = 0; i < insuranceTypes.size(); i++){
                System.out.print(insuranceTypes.get(i)+" ");
            }*/
            company[j] = new InsuranceCompany(companyName, telephone, webAddress, brokerPercentage, description, insuranceTypes);
            //System.out.println(company[j].getCompanyName());
        }
        boolean run = true;
        while(run){
            int choice;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("\nList insurance companies.......1\n"
                             + "Select insurance company.......2\n"
                             + "Search cover...................3\n"
                             + "Exit...........................0\n"
                             + "\nEnter choice:> ");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            switch(choice){
                case 1 : 
                    listInuranceCompanies(company);
                    break;
                case 2 : 
                    System.out.print("Enter company ID from list [1 - "+(company.length)+"] :> ");
                    int selectedCompany;
                    selectedCompany = sc.nextInt();
                    listSingleCompanyDetails(company[selectedCompany-1]);
                    break;
                case 0 :
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default: System.out.println("Invalid choice!, please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)